# SQLite Sum Column based on Date Range

Tags: c#, sqlite, winrt-xaml

Good evening, I have the following table

```
public class SalesRecord
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int SalesRecID { get; set; }

    [Indexed]
    public string SalesRecDate { get; set; }
    public string SalesRecCustName { get; set; }
    public string SalesRecProdName { get; set; }
    public int SalesRecProdQty { get; set; }
    public double SalesRecProdPrice { get; set; }
    public double SalesRecTotalPrice { get; set; }
}
```

and I was able to display rows of items in XAML Listbox.

```
<ListBox Name="listSalesRecord" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SalesRecID}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="30" FontSize="14"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SalesRecDate}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="80" FontSize="14"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SalesRecCustName}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="80" FontSize="14"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SalesRecProdName}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="80" FontSize="14"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SalesRecProdQty}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="60" FontSize="14"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SalesRecProdPrice, Converter={StaticResource Converter}, ConverterParameter=\{0:0.00\}}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="60" FontSize="14"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SalesRecTotalPrice, Converter={StaticResource Converter}, ConverterParameter=\{0:0.00\}}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="60" FontSize="14"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

using the following date range query. There was no problem because I was aware of the `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

```
private void btnSearchRecordDateRange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var searchDateRange = conn.Query<SalesRecord>("SELECT * FROM SalesRecord WHERE date(SalesRecDate) BETWEEN date('" + tbxCDPFrom.Text + "') AND date('" + tbxCDPTo.Text + "')");

        listSalesRecord.ItemsSource = searchDateRange;
    }
```

but now I want to compute Sum of Product Quantity based on Date Range which I want to display in a textbox using the same query, with the only change I made was to replace `SELECT * FROM` with `SELECT SUM(SalesRecProdQty) FROM`. But this same query string failed to give me the sum required.

```
private void btnSearchSumDateRange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        var searchSumProdQty = conn.Query<SalesRecord>("SELECT SUM(SalesRecProdQty) FROM SalesRecord WHERE date(SalesRecDate) BETWEEN date('" +   tbxCDPFrom.Text + "') AND date('" + tbxCDPTo.Text + "')");

        tbxSearchQty.Text = searchSumProdQty.ToString();
   }
```

I got this error message in the textbox:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SalePad.Models.SalesRecord]
```

Can someone tell me where I did wrong.

`SELECT *` worked, but `SELECT SUM(SalesRecProdQty)` failed, even though they used same query string.

I am using SQLite.Net-PCL and I am on WinRT for UWP, not WPF.

Comment: Is that the entirety of the error? Try something like this: SELECT SUM(s.SalesRecProdQty) FROM SalesRecord s WHERE date(s.SalesRecDate) BETWEEN date('" + tbxCDPFrom.Text + "') AND date('" + tbxCDPTo.Text + "')");

Comment: Hi 0______0, I'm still getting the same error System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SalePad.Models.SalesRecord]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to trouble people but I have found the answer

To get the `SUM(SalesRecProdQty)` you have to do this

```
var searchdaterange = conn.Query<SalesRecord>("SELECT * FROM SalesRecord WHERE date(SalesRecDate) BETWEEN date('"+ tbxCDPFrom.Text + "') AND date('"+ tbxCDPTo.Text + "')");

        var sumProdQty = searchdaterange.AsEnumerable().Sum(o => o.SalesRecProdQty);
        tbxSearchQty.Text = sumProdQty.ToString();
```

Would appreciate if someone could explain the logic behind why I am forced to use `AsEnumerable.Sum(o => o.SalesRecProdQty);` because the original syntax would have worked in SQL Fiddle but it refused to work my program.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same issue when selecting specific columns, the reader returns no rows, this is the same for when I use sum(). Selecting * works fine with the exact same query and all my queries work in DB Browser For SQLite, just not in c#.

When using SQLite in C#, you need an indexed column in the columns that you are selecting in your query e.g.

`SELECT table.primaryKey, table.someOtherColumn FROM table`

or in your case

```
SELECT salesRecord.primaryKey, SUM(SalesRecProdQty) FROM SalesRecord WHERE date(SalesRecDate) BETWEEN date('" +   tbxCDPFrom.Text + "') AND date('" + tbxCDPTo.Text + "')
```

The reason selecting */all works is because it is selecting the tables indexed column(s).

Comment: Why has this been down voted... It answers the question.

Comment: I didn't vote but possible reason is that "what happens if you don't have an indexed column?" sounds like you want to ask next question instead of answering